# How to design using Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new in Material Design. Please help me for below structure. How to create?
[image]

I have added text box but I want Label in front of textbox. Please help me.

Comment: why not use <TextField /> component of material-ui. What you have provided is not material design anyways?

Comment: please submit your question with your valuable efforts..

Comment: I am using Material Ui.. given image is just example for layout. Want to label in front of textbox.

Comment: @NitinShinde Material UI doesn't have labels to the side of text fields.  There's a property on the TextField which you can set for the label which follows the material design guidelines.  The label should appear in place of the textfield, like a placeholder, and then move above the text field when the text field is populated.

Answer (score 0):

In Material Design, field label will not put in front of the input field. We will use the placeholder as the label. Check out this [video](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_10/assets/0B7WCemMG6e0VVHhsbWszeEg1c3M/forms-supportive-content-v3_xhdpi.mp4) to see how the field label behaves.

If you want to read more details, here it is:
https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html